# У RadioButton пропадает часть названия внутри контейнера

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени. Динамически создаю GroupBox а в них несколько RadioButton. Суть проблемы в том, что текст RadioButton обрезается на полуслове. ставлю AutoSize - не помогает. GroupBox выравнивается только по высоте, по количеству вложенных RButton'ов а по ширине все равно обрезает названия кнопок. Все боксы создаются в flowLayoutPane. Примечательно что сами GroupBox могут быть нормального размера и по идеи места для текста RadioButton достаточно. У кого была такая проблема подскажите как решить?
вот код :

```
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)       
{
    GroupBox GBstyleName = new GroupBox();
    GBstyleName.Text = table.Columns[i].ToString();
    GBstyleName.Tag = i;
    GBstyleName.AutoSize = true;
    GBstyleName.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    flowLayoutPanelStyles.Controls.Add(GBstyleName);
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
        if (table.Rows[j][i].ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
                RadioButton RB = new RadioButton();
                RB.Margin = new Padding(10, 5, 5, 5);
                RB.Text = table.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                RB.Location = new Point(10, 45 + (20 * j));
                RB.MouseClick += new 
                MouseEventHandler(onRBstyleClick);
                RB.Tag = i.ToString();
                GBstyleName.Controls.Add(RB);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Нужно было просто поставить `AutoSize = true;` в свойства RadioButton.